# Understanding Svelte Stores for complex items

Tags: svelte

I'm trying to understand svelte stores so I can build a shopping cart, update it with products, and render a list of products that are in the cart. So far I have this

My store:

```html
import { writable } from 'svelte/store'

export function cart() {
    const { subscribe, set, update } = writable({});

    return {
        subscribe,
        add: (item) => update(n => Object.assign(item, n)),
        remove: (item) => update(n => n.pop(item)),
        empty: () => set(0)
    };
}
```

My component:

```html
<script>
    import { cart } from '../../stores/cart';
    
    export let product;

    const myCart = cart()

    const addToCart = myCart.add({
        ...product
    })
</script>

<button on:click={addToCart}>
    Add to Cart
</button>
```

Trouble is, I can't find any other documentation and I'm not sure where to go to here. I don't think the store is updating with the product and I don't know how to retrieve products!

Any pointers would help a lot, thank you!

Comment: Have a look at this [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/f7d72f280ff24f74a31d67a0a418f511?version=3.46.2) hope this helps..!

Answer (score 2):

1. You are creating a fresh instance of a cart store within the "Add to cart" component. That instance is accessible nowhere else. What you need is a shared instance of that cart store everyone subscribes to/calls its methods on. One possibility is to move the instance creation into your store file and do `export const myCart = cart()` there, and everybody should import and use that `myCart` store instance.
2. You are invoking the `add` method right away in your component. `const addToCart = myCart.add(..)` means "invoke `add` and store the result of the function call to `addToCart`". What you want `addToCart` to be is a function: `const addToCart = () => myCard.add(..)`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations @dummdidumm, I definitely have no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: You're welcome! If this answers your question, consider to mark it as the correct answer.